# Why is this returning a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

This is a program which fills an array of char pointers with words from a .txt file. Why does the following code return a segmentation fault? Any help is appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *emalloc(size_t s) {
    void *result = malloc(s);
    if (NULL == result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    #define SIZE 100
    char *username[100];
    char word[80];
    int num_words = 0;
    size_t p;
    size_t NumberOfElements;

    /* Read words into array */


    while(1 == scanf("%s", word)) {
        username[num_words] = emalloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(word[0]));
        strcpy(username[num_words], word);
        num_words++;
    }


    /* Print out array */
    NumberOfElements = sizeof(username)/sizeof(username[0]);
    printf("no. %lu\n", NumberOfElements);
    for (p = 0; p < NumberOfElements; p++) {
        printf("%s", username[p]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Error -

```
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Take a debugger and debug it?

Comment: When you stepped through with your debugger, which line raised the fault?

Comment: BTW `%lu` is the wrong format specifier for a `size_t`, you should be using `%zu`

Answer (score 3):

```
NumberOfElements = sizeof(username)/sizeof(username[0]);
```

will always return 100, and if you have entered less than 80 words rest of elements from username will not have been allocated memory, so when you print unallocated pointers it will lead to undefined behaviour

You should loop till `num_words` when you print `username[p]` , instead of looping till `NumberOfElements`

Comment: It is in fact always `100`.

Comment: Thank you, shouldn't have missed that